# Set Redis appenddirname to a S3 path

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, redis

Is there a way to set the directory in which the AOF files are saved to be a S3 bucket path?
(If it's not possible with AOF, I can settle for RDB as well)

My use case:
We have a redis sentinel running as a stateful set inside a kubernetes cluster (amazon eks managed service). We would like to make the data persistent as possible (even if the k8s node itself or the whole cluster crash).

We don't want to use AWS elastic cache service, the goal is to avoid using managed services which costs money.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to have persistent storage for your containers, you may have to look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/, generally EBS(block storage) when you are in AWS.

But, if the goal is to store the files in S3, there are different ways.

- Write a script and run it as a cronjob in Kubernetes that can mount copy the AOF file from sentinel container and upload it to S3 periodically.
- Looks like the standard approach is still being developed as of writing this answer. https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/09/02/cosi-kubernetes-object-storage-management/
- There are open source tools that claims it is possible already.

https://github.com/datashim-io/datashim

https://dev.to/otomato_io/mount-s3-objects-to-kubernetes-pods-12f5

Comment: Thank you very much!
If I want to write a cronjob, do you know a way to copy the aof/rdb file from redis because I couldn't find a redis-cli command to retrieve those files

Comment: 1. you can use "kubectl cp" to copy the file from any pod, if you are running this as cronjob in k8s, cronjob should have access to kubernetes api, or 2. you have to add sidecar sentinel container to your pod that can do either of these, run a webserver, so that from your cronjob pod you can download this file or sidecar container itself runs a script periodically using linux cron